# How to create a temporary cache/table in postgres that lasts the duration of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching

I have a query with a very expensive plsql function that does a lot of recursive computation:

```
SELECT a, b, expensive_recursion(c, d, e) FROM my_table
```

The function expensive_recursion() has plpgsql like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expensive_recursion(col varchar, parent varchar, date varchar)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  _value integer;
  _rec record;
BEGIN

  -- get the value for the current parent that matches the range
  EXECUTE 'SELECT value_'||col||' FROM foo WHERE foo.id = '||quote_literal(parent)||' AND foo.range = '||quote_literal(range) INTO _value;


  -- get all children of parent and sum their values
  FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT child FROM relationships WHERE parent = '||quote_literal(parent) LOOP
    _value = _value + expensive_recursion(col, rec.child, range);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN _value;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE COST 1000;
```

While this works I would like to enable caching not only for the current row that's recursing, but for all rows within the current query, and have the cache cleared once the query has fully executed.

For example, the original function with some pseudo-code:
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION expensive_recursion(col varchar, parent varchar, range varchar)
    RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
      _value integer;
      _rec record;
    BEGIN

```
  -- pseudo-code to check the cache and get the cached value or insert into cache
  IF parent AND range IN cache
    RETURN SELECT value FROM cache WHERE cache.parent = parent and cache.range = range;
  END IF;

  -- get the value for the current parent that matches the range
  EXECUTE 'SELECT value_'||col||' FROM foo WHERE foo.id = '||quote_literal(parent)||' AND foo.range = '||quote_literal(range) INTO _value;


  -- get all children of parent and sum their values
  FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT child FROM relationships WHERE parent = '||quote_literal(parent) LOOP
    _value = _value + expensive_recursion(col, rec.child, range);
  END LOOP;

  -- put new value in cache
  INSERT INTO cache (value, parent, range) VALUES (_value, parent, range);

  -- final value with sum for parent and its children
  RETURN _value;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE COST 1000;
```

Is there a way to do this and have the cache created/deleted? Could I use temp tables or maybe some structure/type I manage in the plpgsql function. The trick is multiple users can execute this function and for app-specific reasons the cache cannot be shared across queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary table like a normal table; just qualify it accordingly:

```
create temporary table ( … );
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

There is tiny downside and a potentially major upside in doing so. The downside is that, if the temporary set is small, you're creating and subsequently deleting rows in the catalog, and adding dead rows in the process that then need to be vacuumed. The upside is that, if the temporary set is large, you can create an index on it and ultimately `analyze` the table before proceeding to query it.

You can control whether the temp table is dropped at the end of the transaction or at the end of the session using `on commit` in its definition.

Adding to this, though, another way to do recursive queries is to use a CTE, also called a with query:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

For all intents and purposes, it creates an anonymous (and non-indexed) temporary table. You can do this recursively, and doing so can be fairly efficient.

Methinks try changing your query and the underlying logic so as to try to use a CTE first. If all else fails, then look into actually using temporary tables.